# When I am trying to load data into word using BI Publisher I am getting Message39 error

Tags: oracle

When I am trying to load data into word using BI Publisher I am getting Message39 error. How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Are your BI Publisher and MS Office versions compatible?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error which occure when you use MS Word 32bit and 64bit BI Publisher i.e. mismatching bit size.

Please install 64bit MS Word (available) or 32bit BI Publisher (if available)